# Software to watch changes on web and machine with ability to automaticaly act on them?

Tags: software-recommendation, monitoring

I am in need of software which can do all of the following:

- Monitor:

  - Web pages
  - RSS Feeds
  - Files
  - Folders
  - Ports
  - Social Networks (e.g.: FaceBook)
  - Processes
  - Email (e.g.: POP3, IMAP and GMail)
- Run custom commands when items being watched change
- Alert the user through the built-in notifications system of any changes to watched items

Is there an application which can do all of this? I am running Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 with GNOME 3.20.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Specto** is just what you are looking for!

Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install specto
```

**Description:**

```
Unobtrusive update notification program
 Specto is a desktop application that will watch any user-specified events
 (web, folder, ...). This will allow users, for instance, to specify a website
 to watch, and Specto will automatically check for updates on the web page. It
 will then notify the user when there is activity. This will allow the user to
 be informed of new updates/events instead of having to look out for them.
```

**Screenshots:**

[image: Example Main Window]

[image: Example Preferences Window]

[image: Example Watch Commands Window]